# HERE map exception "cannot initialize the engine twice". Android 5.0.1

Tags: android, here-api

When I try to initialize MapFragment of HERE map library, an exception occurs. On android 5.0. Android 4.2 works fine.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize the engine twice
at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.<init>(MapsEngine.java:585)
at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.b(MapsEngine.java:874)
at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.b(MapsEngine.java:391)
at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:343)
at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:129)
at com.nokia.maps.br.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:126)
at    com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment.init(MapFragment.java:108)
at com.reverllc.rever.map.MapFragment.setUpMapView(MapFragment.java:366)
at com.reverllc.rever.map.MapFragment.onRideStatusUpdate(MapFragment.java:649)
at com.reverllc.rever.service.TrackingServiceManager.invokeStatusListeners(TrackingServiceManager.java:135)
at com.reverllc.rever.service.TrackingServiceManager.access$600(TrackingServiceManager.java:27)
at com.reverllc.rever.service.TrackingServiceManager$IncomingHandler.handleMessage(TrackingServiceManager.java:276)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

My Map Fragment is located in LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> 

    ........................................
```

On Activity class I get may fragment by id. And I call init method only once. When trying init map an exception occurs. I put breakpoints and I was convinced that init method call only once. I was doing all that is written in the [official article HEREmap](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html)

Method onCreate in my activity with mapFragment:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setUsingEventBus(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


    mapFragment = (com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapfragment);
    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                OnEngineInitListener.Error error)
        {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                map = mapFragment.getMap();
                map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                        com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.Animation.NONE);
                map.setZoomLevel(
                        (map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
            } else {
                Log.d("MapFragment","ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help fix this issue?

UPDATE

application logcat [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r84jbwc9exsaxva/app%20logcat?dl=0"dropbox")

Comment: The code looks OK, I think there may be another error hidden within adb logcat. Can you try to collect some logs and post it here? The most probable cause is if the native libraries are not packaged in your application.

Comment: @David Leong, I added app logcat file. I want to remind that on android 4.2 it works fine

Comment: Sorry still not enough information. Instead of calling MapFragment.init(), can you please try to use MapsEngine.init() ? The signature should be identical. Does the use of MapEngine.init() return ErrorNone?

Comment: @David Leong, when I call MapsEngine.init() , there is the same problem-"Cannot initialize the engine twice"

Comment: Seems like you have a service as well from your logcat. It is very likely you are trying to init the map engine in both the service and the application side? They must be in the same process?

Comment: @DavidLeong, I even tried to remove the service from the manifest file and run the application, but the problem remains

Comment: Sorry, in this case I suggest you to contact our customer support team with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems!!
I found a similar log.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
My solution is that only do mapFragment.init() in onCreate(). Other events are moved to onStart().

Comment: That is generally OK, just means the device os a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

In marshmallow you need to add 4 permission and your map will working fine

```
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
int FourthPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
int SecondPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
int ThirdPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Use this link for multiple permission

[Request Check Multiple Run time Permissions at once in android Marshmallow](http://www.android-examples.com/request-check-multiple-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow/)